# 'insert into ... on duplicate key' with auto increment

Tags: php, sql, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to do an INSERT only if the combination of two columns (a and b) does not exist already. Otherwise, I want to do an UPDATE. The issue of the following code is that it always INSERTs a new row instead of updating when I want to. The reason I think, is because I don't manage do have a kind of two-unique-column in the settings of my table.
Does any one have a solution? Google doesn't seem to be my friend today..

The table:

```
id : int, primary,  AI
a b c and d : int
```

The code:

```
$req = $connexion -> prepare("
INSERT INTO position (a,b,c,d)
VALUES (:a,:b,:c,:d)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
c=:c;");
$position->bindParam(':a', $a);
$position->bindParam(':b', $b);
$position->bindParam(':c', $c);
$position->bindParam(':d', $d);
$a = $val_a;
$b = $val_b;
$c = $val_c;
$d = $val_d;
$req -> execute();
```

Comment: a b c d none of these are columns in your database table have a UNIQUE index. ID is the primary key, so it will work with duplicate ids. You need to add a UNIQUE INDEX on one of these columns to get it working.

Comment: Add a unique key - `ALTER TABLE position ADD UNIQUE KEY (a,b)`

Comment: @Sean Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY` requires a `UNIQUE KEY` if you are not matching to the `PRIMARY KEY`. You can add a `UNIQUE KEY` by using an `ALTER TABLE` query

```
ALTER TABLE position ADD UNIQUE KEY (a,b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried to alter the table to reflect what you need? try this before executing your code.

```
ALTER TABLE `position` ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(`a`, `b`);
```